# Install laravel and backoffice via composer (fresh install and integration)

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I'm looking foward to create projects on laravel via composer but instead of creating a fresh install I want to install the "backoffice repository" that i'm developing for my company.

So, I created a Laravel 8.0 project and installed the orchid platform on it. Now I want to develop functionalities on it and everytime I create a website I want to "pull" the backoffice into the website (fresh website and already built websites). So a installation and a integration. I've did some research and I tought about using composer....

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Most probably, this is possible. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Hello, I've check some tutorial where they create a folder for the package and develop the package inside the folder. I'm stuck because i don't want to create that folder. I want to create a package with the whole project. Or, if it's possible, just with the backoffice funcionalities so i can implement the new backoffice on the already developed websites. I'm stuck on the very first step and the researches don't give me anything useful

Comment: And what keeps you from creating such a package?

Comment: My point here is that i want to create a package with the whole project. Can you please tell me how or give me any link so I can read about it?

Comment: I understood that you want to do that - I don't get what you are asking for, What have you tried to create that package? What **exactly** is not working?